# Hamming numbers

Tags: code-golf, sequence, number-theory, restricted-time

[Hamming numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_numbers) are numbers which evenly divide a power of 60. Equivalently, their prime factors are all \$ \le 5 \$.

Given a positive integer, print that many Hamming numbers, in order.

Rules:

- Input will be a positive integer \$n \le 1,000,000 \$
- Output should be the first \$n\$ terms of https://oeis.org/A051037
- Execution time must be \$<1\$ minute
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf); shortest code wins

Comment: Which aim an answer should have? Golf? Most effective algorithm? Just searching of solution methods?

Comment: Sorry for not being specific. I haven't solved this myself, so I'm not sure if the bounds I put in are reasonable. Please let me know.

Comment: [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A051037)

Comment: 1 is a Hamming number, so, printing 1,000,000 `1`s is conformant with your specs. It will also be in order, i.e. not an unordered sequence. :)

Comment: Please add the definition of a Hamming number to your question.

Comment: I tried finding out what the 10^6th Hamming number: J B's Haskell post andfR0DDY's Python post showed different values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Haskell, <s>101</s> <s>97</s> 92+|n| characters

```
h=1:m 2h&m 3h&m 5h
m=map.(*)
c@(a:b)&o@(m:n)|a<m=a:b&o|a>m=m:c&n|0<1=a:b&n
main=print$take 1000000h
```

Computes the full million in 3.7s on the machine I tested on (variably more if you actually want the output stored)

Ungolfed:

```
-- print out the first million Hamming numbers
main = print $ take 1000000 h

-- h is the entire Hamming sequence.
-- It starts with 1; for each number in the
-- sequence, 2n, 3n and 5n are also in.
h = 1 : (m 2 h) & (m 3 h) & (m 5 h)

-- helper: m scales a list by a constant factor
m f xs = map (f*) xs

-- helper: (&) merges two ordered sequences
a@(ha:ta) & b@(hb:tb)
    |    ha < hb = ha : ta & b
    |    ha > hb = hb :  a & tb
    |  otherwise = ha : ta & tb
```

All Haskell is notoriously good at: defining a list as a lazy function of itself, in a way that actually works.

Comment: You don't get the positive integer parameter, that add more size to your code

Comment: @Zhen The positive integer parameter is the second-to-last token, and its size is declared outfront in the header.

Answer (score 4):

**Python 181 Characters**

```
h=[]        
h.append(1)
n=input()
i=j=k=0
while n:
    print h[-1]
    while h[i]*2<=h[-1]:
        i+=1
    while h[j]*3<=h[-1]:
        j+=1
    while h[k]*5<=h[-1]:
        k+=1
    h.append(min(h[i]*2,h[j]*3,h[k]*5))
    n-=1
```

Comment: How is this 181 chars? I've saved this to a file, removing the whitespace after `h=[]`, using a minimum tab distance, and single character line breaks, and the file size ends up being 187 bytes.

Comment: Anyway... Trivial optimization: `h=[1]`. Also, give a number directly in the source code, to save characters for numbers `<1000000`.

Comment: And oops, sorry, didn't realize the answer is super-old.

Comment: @nitro2k01, I make it 183 chars. (There's some trailing whitespace at the end of the first line, and the indentation should be a space for one level and a tab for two levels).

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>34</s> 23 bytes

```apl
{⍺⍴{⍵[⍋⍵]}∪,⍵∘.×⍳5}⍣≡∘1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/7VHbhOpHvbse9W4BUlujH/V2A6nY2kcdq3SAjEcdM/QOT3/Uu9m09lHv4kedC4EChkBdCkZcaQqGBgZcj3o69BXSFEwNQAAA)

TIO throws a WS FULL error for \$n = 1000000\$, but Dyalog on my laptop runs in about 45 seconds, not counting the scrolling to display numbers.

```apl
{⍺⍴{⍵[⍋⍵]}∪,⍵∘.×⍳5}⍣≡∘1     Monadic function:
{⍺⍴{⍵[⍋⍵]}∪,⍵∘.×⍳5}         Define the following helper function g(⍺,⍵):
             ⍵∘.×⍳5             Make a multiplication table between ⍵ and (1 2 3 4 5).
                                (Including 4 is unnecessary but saves bytes.)
            ,                   Flatten the table into an array.
           ∪                    Keep unique elements.
    {⍵[⍋⍵]}                     Grade up the array and access it at those indices.
                                (This is the APL idiom to sort an array.)
 ⍺⍴                             Keep the first ⍺ elements; pad by repeating the array.
{⍺⍴{⍵[⍋⍵]}∪,⍵∘.×⍳5}⍣≡       Repeatedly apply g with some fixed left argument
                             until a fixed point is reached.
                             At this point we have a dyadic function that takes
                             n on the left and the starting value on the right,
                             and returns multiples of the n Hamming numbers.
                      ∘1     Fix 1 as the right argument.
```

Comment: Shuffling things around saves four: [`1↓0 1{⍺↑{⍵[⍋⍵]}∪,⍵∘.×⍳5}⍣≡⍨1+⊢`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///3/BR22QDBcPqR727HrVNBFJbox/1dgOp2NpHHat0gIxHHTP0Dk9/1LvZtPZR7@JHnQsf9a4w1H7Uteh/2qO2CY96@x71TfX0f9TVfGi9MdAIIC84yBlIhnh4Bv9PUzDiSlMwNDDgetTToa@QpmBqAAIA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Comment: FYI, `{⍺⍴∧∪,⍵×⍀⍳5}\`⍣≡∘1` in Extended. (Backtick needed due to bug.)

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 8 bytes

```
λdǏG7<;ȯ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=%CE%BBd%C7%8FG7%3C%3B%C8%AF&inputs=200&header=&footer=)

```
λ     ;ȯ # First n numbers where
 dǏG     # Maximum of prime factors
    7<   # Less than 7
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), <s>29</s> 26 bytes, times out when n>=200,000 on online interpreter.

My first ever Vyxal post.
29->26, adviced by @lyxal.

```
6ɽ{:L?<|:2*$:3*$:5*∪∪∪}s?Ẏ
```

### How it works

```
# let first hamming numbers are 1 to 6
6ɽ
# while items of they are less than n; do
{:L?<|
# for each item, multiply with those numbers
# and then unify them; done
  :2*$:3*$:5*∪∪∪}
# sort
s
# take first n items
?Ẏ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=6%C9%BD%7B%3AL%3F%3C%7C%3A2*%24%3A3*%24%3A5*%E2%88%AA%E2%88%AA%E2%88%AA%7Ds%3F%E1%BA%8E&inputs=200&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby - <strike>154</strike> 231 characters

```
def k i,n;(l=Math).log(i,2)*l.log(i,3)*l.log(i,5)/6>n end
def l i,n;k(i,n)?[i]:[i]+l(5*i,n)end
def j i,n;k(i,n)?[i]:[i]+j(3*i,n)+l(5*i,n)end
def h i,n;k(i,n)?[i]:[i]+h(2*i,n)+j(3*i,n)+l(5*i,n)end
puts h(1,n=gets.to_i).sort.first n
```

And now it's fast enough, there is definitely a lot of golfing that can still happen though.

```
→ time echo 1000000 | ruby golf-hamming.rb | wc
1000000 1000000 64103205
echo 1000000  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 0.003 total
ruby golf-hamming.rb  40.39s user 0.81s system 99% cpu 41.229 total
wc  1.58s user 0.05s system 3% cpu 41.228 total
```

Answer (score 2):

## MMIX, 92 bytes (23 instrs)

I'm cheating a bit; instead of printing (which would take a lot of work, this being machine language), I instead pass the numbers to a function passed in!

```
00000000: fe020004 34000100 e3030000 c1040300  “£¡¥4¡¢¡ẉ¤¡¡Ḋ¥¤¡
00000010: e7030001 da040403 3c040304 1d050403  ḃ¤¡¢ḷ¥¥¤<¥¤¥ø¦¥¤
00000020: feff0006 6204ff05 43fffffd 1d050405  “”¡©b¥”¦C””’ø¦¥¦
00000030: feff0006 6204ff05 43fffffd 31ff0401  “”¡©b¥”¦C””’1”¥¢
00000040: 5bfffff3 e7000001 c1050300 bf040100  [””ṙḃ¡¡¢Ḋ¦¤¡Ḃ¥¢¡
00000050: 5b00ffef f6040002 f8000000           [¡”ṁẇ¥¡£ẏ¡¡¡
```

```
smooth5 GET    $2,rJ
        NEG    $0,1,$0      // n = 1 - n
        SETL   $3,0         // i = 0
0H      SET    $4,$3
        INCL   $3,1         // loop: j = i++
        SADD   $4,$4,$3     // j = popcnt(j & ~i)
        SR     $4,$3,$4     // j = i >> j (cheap way of getting out factors of 2)
1H      DIV    $5,$4,3      // lp3: k = j / 3
        GET    $255,rR      // tmp = j % 3
        CSZ    $4,$255,$5   // if(!tmp) j = k
        BZ     $255,1B      // if(!tmp) goto lp3
1H      DIV    $5,$4,5      // lp5: k = j / 5
        GET    $255,rR      // tmp = j % 5
        CSZ    $4,$255,$5   // if(!tmp) j = k
        BZ     $255,1B      // if(!tmp) goto lp3
        CMP    $255,$4,1    // tmp = j <=> 1
        PBNZ   $255,0B      // iflikely(tmp) goto loop
        INCL   $0,1         // n++
        SET    $5,$3
        PUSHGO $4,$1,0      // f(i)
        PBNZ   $0,0B        // iflikely(n) goto loop
        PUT    rJ,$2
        POP    0,0          // return
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
RḤÆfṀ€<7T
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/o4Y4lh9vSHu5seNS0xsY85P///4YGAA)

Returns all hamming numbers under n.

**How?**

```
RḤÆfṀ€<7T     Main Link. Takes n on the left
        T     Filter by
R             Inclusive range
 Ḥ            Double each
  Æf          Prime factors
     €        For each
    Ṁ         Maximum
      <7      Less than 7
```

My first serious jelly answer

Comment: Unfortunately, [8 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjiWH29Ie7mywMT@09Vj7////DQ3AAAA) doesn't work with the time limit :(

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing yeah, IO rules suck

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 97 bytes

Inefficient but golfy. Lot's of keywords and whitespace, so potential for more golfing.

```python
def f(n):
 h=[1]
 while(n:=n-1):h+=[min(j*k for j in(2,3,5)for k in h if j*k not in h)]
 return h
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JZDNboMwEITvPMWKE25dCf8AJhKHXipVrdQHQNwKgiR1IkJU9enpjHOwPbM79n7y9W@bL9GF67rv3@MkUxHVIZO5682Qye@8nMciHrr4YtRhfu76nyUWx6eTTJdVjgJjtdOVoj3ByizLJAzEy5a8wjPruN1X6H0bb5t00hstVovT4rVUWmotQUurxZRY6BgUDaoGZYuaRc6iZhvcgne8jb6H9qh75CroCrkaZ42zQaZBL8AHDGxxtnyz5JAycFIax1mW1lF5z/Fs1GkjDZ8wrSULYUhmE45PbI5wVBUbDVUIBE2kafPkpSKRC57oZC@rIcvW8XY/81@m4jzGgp@kVJZd1yVuRZ@/vb5/5jr/@siH/hHtOmYG/XBq/wc)

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 165 bytes

Slightly golfed version of the [original Python entry](/a/466/86751).

Reposted, because of its age.

```python
def f(n):
 h=[1];i=j=k=0
 while(n:=n-1):
  m=h[-1]
  while(h[i]*2<=m):i+=1
  while(h[j]*3<=m):j+=1
  while(h[k]*5<=m):k+=1
  h+=[min(h[i]*2,h[j]*3,h[k]*5)]
 return h
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVBLboMwFNxziidWkDgS/gAmrRfdVKpaqQdA3pXI5ONGhKjq6ekb00W7sD1vZuwZ@fo9h8@o7XValo/hQIcilvuMguulfxjd0Z1cldFXGM9DEfcu7iRkurjQ76RntEqhH/1GPbpLuR@3Tv7hj36jE3/8z5/8pk78aeXD1vWXMf6@JNaLYvWVHDQN832KFJZ5uM3kqJeClCAtyAiqBTWCrKBOkKx4sSKZlMxKphVzin2KOdXyLZ41brNuGBvmDftqxjX7Gj4bPlv2tKxZni0Hdnx2eLNCSGWRlOKQpTBqIGMQD6FJG9rgCdkpdEEZNFOpjkndNMoB1RBaIGtRNDVNm0FfIDTS1qA6ule1z7JpuN3P@JdDcR5igU8qyyy7TmOciz5/fnp5y0X@/pr7frU6B48X61QuPw)

Answer (score 1):

## [GAWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) `-M`, <s>138</s> 120 bytes.

It was originally [a post on rosetta code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hamming_numbers#AWK).
Without `-M` it overflows when huge value is input.

```
{a=2
b=3
c=5
for(s=h[0]=1;--$0;c-z||c=5*h[++k]){z=a<b?a:b
s=s" "(z=h[++n]=z<c?z:c)
a-z||a=2*h[++i]
b-z||b=3*h[++j]}}$0=s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY1BCoMwEEX3c4oiLrQSiC3dqIMn6AlkFkmgaAVTOoVC1Kt3mrh8PN7/5juLrAYvYPEKDm/w8O@CcRw0Yd0qlevWqbBtUZ3HoapmKteAprO9aSwwcnbKioBJLYShc31oXAkmNXH2aCYCmzheHPykfc81skitf/71mfzCou5/)

### Usage

Given from stdin, as a line consists of a string of decimal natural number.

### Execution time

Tested in my Termux. CPU is:

```
Architecture:        aarch64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              8
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-7
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  4
Socket(s):           2
Vendor ID:           ARM
Model:               4
Model name:          Cortex-A53
Stepping:            r0p4
CPU max MHz:         1768.0000
CPU min MHz:         449.0000
BogoMIPS:            52.00
Flags:               fp asimd evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32
```

#### With original code

10^6th Hamming number is `519312780448388736089589843750000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`.

```
$ time echo 1000000 | awk -Mf Textfile/ham.awk
# lots of output
real    2m36.842s
user    0m25.224s
sys     0m5.356s
```

#### If `$0=s` is removed

```
$ time echo 1000000 | awk -Mf Textfile/ham.awk
real    0m25.404s
user    0m24.676s
sys     0m0.716s
```

### Note

- Original 138 bytes of post outputs incorrectly: it outputs n+1 numbers, not n.

Comment: OBTW replacing variables a,b,c,i,j,k with arrays resulted in 132 bytes. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XUxLCsIwEN17ilBKsQ2BdKGbON7AE4Qs3Ggm0kRUEKbt1R0nLl29/zu/b8zzpTy2CHtnDB5H108eA@CmutFboRK01iFgoxrqZ4LoddY6DLtfKSnMapJZCgfquuhzAIIq/2NDy1IR0iAX@io0rGtrAZlH@yn3F5b8ZHP6Ag "AWK – Try It Online")

Comment: @tailsparkrabbitear In the case 130 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XUxLCsIwEN17ilBCsQ2BZKGbON7AE4RZuJFMpIlUQUjbqzsmLl29/7u@78zLLc97gqPTms7WDZMnBNo1N3hTaQ2kdQTUia4MS4HgVVIKx8OvFAUlMdVZxFPp@@ATQoEm/2Nd1rUhxLFeKBlx26QBYrbmkx8vyunJ@vIF "AWK – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 110 bytes

```js
f=h=>eval("g=n=>n-1n?n%2n?n%3n?n%5n?0:g(n/5n):g(n/3n):g(n/2n):1;r=[i=1n];while(!r[h-1])if(g(++i))r.push(i);r")
```

Theoretically works for arbitrarily large inputs, but prohibitively slow.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 7 bytes

```
ЧdḟG7<Ẇ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIiLCLQp2ThuJ9HNzzhuoYiLCIiLCI0MCIsIjMuNC4xIl0=)

Port of Emanrasu's Vyxal answer

Answer (score 0):

### Ursala, 103

```
#import std
#import nat
smooth"p" "n" = ~&z take/"n" nleq-< (rep(length "n") ^Ts/~& product*K0/"p") <1>
```

**Output** for `main = smooth<2,3,5>* nrange(1,20)`

```
<1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,12,15,16,18,20,24,25,27,30,32,36>
```

Answer (score -2):

### Haskell, 71

```
h n = drop n $ iterate (\(_,(a:t))-> (a,union t [2*a,3*a,5*a])) (0,[1])
```

**Output**

```
*Main> map fst $ take 20 $ h 1
[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,12,15,16,18,20,24,25,27,30,32,36]
```

Comment: The spec calls for you to print, so the code to print should be counted. This also allows a fair comparison against the other Haskell implementation.

Comment: @PeterTaylor How many characters do you think I should add?