# Codegolf the sequence of distance-3 Hamming Codewords (A075926)

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence, error-correction

Codegolf the [hamming code](https://oeis.org/A075926) (with distance equals 3)!

The sequence looks like this: 0, 7, 25, 30, 42, 45, 51, 52, 75, 76, 82, 85, 97, 102, 120, 127, 385, 390, 408, 415, 427, 428, 434, 437, 458, 461, 467, 468, 480, 487, 505, 510, 642, 645, 667, 668, 680...

### Task

Given `n` output the first `n` items in OEIS sequence A075926. Your program should work for any integer `n` where `0 <= n < 2^15`. This sequence is known as the sequence of hamming codewords with distance being 3.

**Rules:**

- Post both an ungolfed version of your code (or an explatation), and the golfed version, so that other people can understand how it works
- If your program is written in a language with a compiler, specify which compiler and the compiler settings you used. Non-standard language features are allowed as long as it compiles with the compiler you specified, and the compiler was created prior to this question

**Sequence Definition:**
Given a distance 3 hamming codeword `k`, the variants of `k` are `k` itself, and any nonnegative integer that can be produced by flipping one of `k`'s bits. The `n`th hamming codeword is the smallest nonnegative integer that doesn't share a variant with any preceeding distance 3 hamming codeword. Here are the first twenty d-3 hamming codewords in binary:

> 0,
>   111,
>   11001,
>   11110,
>   101010,
>   101101,
>   110011,
>   110100,
>   1001011,
>   1001100,
>   1010010,
>   1010101,
>   1100001,
>   1100110,
>   1111000,
>   1111111,
>   110000001,
>   110000110,
>   110011000,
>   110011111,
>   110101011

**Ungolfed C++ code to produce sequence:**

```
//Flips the nth bit
size_t flipN(size_t val, int bit) {
    return val ^ (1ull << bit);
}
void Hamming(size_t n) {
    int bits_to_use = 20;
    //This vector keeps track of which numbers are crossed off
    //As either hamming codewords or their variants.
    std::vector<bool> vect(1ull << bits_to_use, false);
    size_t pos = 0;
    size_t val = 0;
    while(val <= n) {
        //Checks to see that pos hasn't been crossed off
        if(vect[pos]) goto loopend;
        for(int i=0; i < bits_to_use; ++i)
        {
            if(vect[flipN(pos, i)]) goto loopend;
            //Checks to see that none of the variants
            //of pos have been crossed off
        }
        //If both those conditions are satisfied, output pos
        //As the next hamming codeword
        cout << pos << endl;
        //Here we cross off all the variants
        vect[pos] = true;
        for(int i=0; i < bits_to_use; ++i)
        {
            vect[flipN(pos, i)] = true;
        }
        ++val;
        loopend:
        ++pos;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7/hamming-numbers?rq=1)

Comment: No; they're very different sequences. The Hamming Numbers question is for https://oeis.org/A051037

Comment: I edited your post to clarify the task and I removed some rules that are already defaults (see meta). Rollback if you would like to.

Comment: Am I the only on that doesn't understand the task? :P

Comment: Given a number n, output the first n numbers of integer sequence A051037. It's a pretty standard problem to output an integer sequence; this particular integer sequence just requires an interesting algorithm.

Comment: Some Test cases would be helpful (although we have OEIS)

Comment: @JorgePerez You should be able to explain this algorithm and give examples

Comment: The sequence is defined neither here nor on the OEIS page.

Comment: _"Post both an ungolfed version of your code, and the golfed version, so that other people can understand how it works"_ What does ungolfed Pyth or Jelly look like? I suggest you ask for an explanation instead. :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>98</s> 97 bytes

<sup>-1 byte thanks to Mr. Xcoder</sup>

```python
x=input()
l=[]
i=0
while len(l)<x:s=any(bin(i^n).count('1')<3for n in l);i+=s;l+=[i]*-~-s
print l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBDoIwEAXQfU/RHTMSDMpOmJMQTNRgmGTy29ASYOPV63vxzEvAvZRDFHHLxM5knJxK6/ZFbfY2g4yH45HkhZPeCtIn@PoJGzJVt4qH7htWD6/wxr3WknqrZdTp0vya5OKqyN5K6do/)

Straightforward implementation, using `xor` to calculate the hamming distance.
The inner loop is equivalent to :

```python
if any(bin(i^n).count('1')<3 for n in l):
   i+=1
else:
   l.append(i)
```

Comment: `(1-s)` is `-~-s` ([97 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcFBDoIwEAXQfU/RHTMSDMpOmJMQTNRgmGTy29ASYOPV63vxzEvAvZRDFHHLxM5knJxK6/ZFbfY2g4yH45HkhZPeCtIn@PoJGzJVt4qH7htWD6/wxr3WknqrZdTp0vya5OKqyN5K6do/))

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), <s>34 21</s> 19 bytes

*Special Thanks to [@LeakyNun](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48934/leaky-nun) for golfing off **half of my solution!***

```
u+Gf.Am<2sjxdT2G0QY
```

**[Try it here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=u%2BGf.Am%3C2sjxdT2G0QY&input=10&debug=0)** or **[Check out the test Suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=u%2BGf.Am%3C2sjxdT2G0QY&input=1%0A&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9&debug=0)**.

---

Alternative, 19-byte solutions ([Try one here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=u%2BGf-Zm%3C2sjxdT2GZQY&input=10&debug=0)):

```
u+Gf-Zm<2sjxdT2GZQY
u+Gf-0m<2sjxdT2G0QY
u+Gf.Am<2sjxdT2GZQY
```

Comment: [21 bytes](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=u%2BGf.Am%3E%2F.BxdT%5C12G0QY&input=10&debug=0)

Comment: [19 bytes](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=u%2BGf.Am%3C2sjxdT2G0QY&input=10&debug=0)

Comment: @LeakyNun Thanks again, editing