# Non-Hamming numbers

Tags: code-golf, sequence, number-theory

[Hamming number](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_number) (also known as regular number) is a number that evenly divides powers of 60.
[We already have a task to do something with it.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/7/100411)
This time we are going to do the opposite.

I define non-Hamming number as in: \$n\$ is non-Hamming number if and only if it satisfies following two conditions:

- \$n\$ is positive integer, and
- \$n\$ does not divide powers of 60 evenly; i.e. \$60^m\mod n\neq0\$ for all positive integer \$m\$.

Make a program, a function, or a subroutine that does one of these:

1. takes no input to print/return/generate a list of non-Hamming numbers infinitely, or
2. takes a positive integer \$n\$ as input to print/return/generate \$n\$th non-Hamming number (can be either 0-indexed or 1-indexed), or
3. takes a positive integer \$n\$ as input to print/return/generate a list of first \$n\$ non-Hamming numbers.

4. <s>takes a positive integer \$n\$ to print/return/generate non-Hamming number until \$n\$ (suggested by @Wasif, can be inclusive or not; i.e. non-Hamming numbers that are either \$<n\$ or \$\leq n\$).</s> abolished by @rak1507.

## Example

This example shows how program/function/subroutine that does 3rd task should work:

- Input: `5`
- Output: `7, 11, 13, 14, 17`

## Rules

- [I/O method is done by your desired format.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)
- If you are answering one of 2nd or 3rd task, you can assume that input is a non-negative integer.
- No external resources.
- [Standard loopholes apply.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)
- If your program/function/subroutine fails to output huge non-Hamming numbers because of overflow (or similar boundary) but is theotically valid, it is acceptable.
- Shortest code in bytes wins. However, if someone have won entire of this post, you can still try to win among languages and tasks.

## P.S.

It's actually [A279622](http://oeis.org/A279622).

Comment: [sandbox was here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22022/100411)

Comment: I'd usually say that a challenge of outputting not-X numbers is too similar to one of outputting X numbers, though here maybe it's justified because [the previous challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/7/20260) has a restrictive time limit and fewer output options.

Comment: Is it allowed to take until what number to print non hamming numbers like take 15 and output 1,7,11,13?

Comment: @Wasif good idea; \$<n\$ or \$ \leq n\$?

Comment: @tailsparkrabbitear \$<n\$ should be better, should   I post my answer following that

Comment: <= n would be ok too

Comment: @Wasif then I should accept both.

Comment: @tailsparkrabbitear I disagree with allowing 'numbers up to n' as it goes against normal sequence challenge convention.

Comment: @rak1507, thank you for feedback; then I need to unadopt Wasif's suggestion.

Comment: @tailsparkrabbitear Although I agree with (and upvoted) rak1507's comment, I nevertheless disagree with changing the rules retrospectively in a way that invalidates existing answers.  At the very least, you need to go-through the answers and alert the affected authors that you've invalidated them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

*-1 thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs).*

```
∞ʒÓg3›
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Uce8U5MOT043ftSw6/9/AA)

```
∞ʒÓg3›  # full program
 ʒ      # all elements of...
∞       # [1, 2, 3, ...]...
 ʒ      # where...
   g    # the length of...
  Ó     # the exponents of the prime factorization of...
        # (implicit) current element in list...
     ›  # is greater than...
    3   # literal
        # implicit output
```

Comment: [6 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Uce8U5MOT043ftSw6/9/AA) using the exponents of the prime factorization.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
30*%µƇ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/YQEv10NZj7f///zc0BQA)

Takes \$n\$ and outputs all non-Hamming numbers \$\le n\$, as [allowed by the OP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/223789/non-hamming-numbers/223790#comment518825_223789).

Thanks to [Delfad0r](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/82619/delfad0r) for [suggesting this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57693842#57693842) method in chat!

---

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
ÆfṀ>5Ʋ#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW9rDnQ12psc2Kf//bwoA)

-2 bytes thanks to [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor), who noted that \$k\$ is a non-Hamming number if it's <s>smallest</s> largest (thanks [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs), for catching that) prime factor is greater than \$5\$!

Returns the first \$n\$ non-Hamming numbers

---

### How they work

```
30*%µƇ - Main link. Takes n on the left
    µƇ - Filter the range i ∈ [1, 2, ..., n] on the following:
30*    -   Raise 30 to the power i
   %   -   That is not divisible by i?

ÆfṂ>5Ʋ# - Main link. Takes no arguments
     Ʋ  - Group the previous 4 links into a monad f(k):
Æf      -   Prime factors of k
  Ṁ     -   Maximum
   >5   -   Greater than 5?
      # - Read n from STDIN and count up k = 1, 2, 3, ... until n such k return True under f(k)
```

Comment: Might it be shorter to check whether the smallest prime factor of `k` is greater than 5?

Comment: @xnor Yep, that does it. Math wins as usual :)

Comment: I think there was a typo in xnor's comment, it should be the largest prime factor. (14 is now missing from your output,)

Comment: @ovs ...yes, can't believe I didn't notice that

Answer (score 6):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 61 bytes

A full program that prints the sequence forever.

```javascript
for(k=6;x=++k;)[2,3,5].some(g=d=>x%d?x<2:g(d,x/=d))||print(k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/Py2/SCPb1sy6wlZbO9taM9pIx1jHNFavOD83VSPdNsXWrkI1xb7CxsgqXSNFp0LfNkVTs6amoCgzr0QjW/P/fwA)

#### Commented

```javascript
for(               // infinite loop:
  k = 6;           //   start with k = 6
  x = ++k;         //   increment k and copy it to x
)                  //
  [2, 3, 5]        // list of primes less than 7
  .some(g = d =>   // for each of them:
    x % d ?        //   if d is not a divisor of x:
      x < 2        //     return true if x = 1
    :              //   else:
      g(d, x /= d) //     divide x by d and do a recursive call
  )                // end of some()
  ||               // if true, k is 5-smooth (aka regular, aka Hamming number)
  print(k)         // otherwise, print it
```

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 65 bytes

Returns the \$n\$<sup>th</sup> term of the sequence, 1-indexed.

```javascript
f=(n,k=6)=>n?f(n-[2,3,5].every(g=d=>x%d?x>1:g(d,x/=d),x=++k),k):k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dc1BCoMwEEDRvaeYhYUMiba22IV29CCloJgoNjIpWiRFPHvq7i8e/He7tks3j59vwk6bEHoSrCzdkSque8HJ86puKn@lZjXzTwykqfInXfsqKwahlT@TRuVJSovKYmFD72bBQJCVwPAgyC9HSImwRQCd48VNJp3cIJpWxBvveNh4O1a4N1hGe/gD)

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 25 bytes

```
(>:[]echo~5<{:@q:)@]^:_&7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NeysomNTkzPy60xtqq0cCq00HWLjrOLVzP9rcoGEFdIU1NX/AwA)

YAIOXI

> Yet Another Implementation Of xnor's Idea.

- `^:_&7` Loop forever, starting with 7:
- `]echo~...` Echo the current count if...
- `5<{:@q:` 5 is less than the last `{:` prime factor `q:` (they're listed in ascending order).  This step is merely a side effect.
- `>:[` Return the increment of the counter and keep looping.

Comment: +1 for the emoticons :)

Comment: can probably be shortened now the challenge author has made the (wrong) decision to allow non hamming numbers up to n

Comment: sadly i think expressing condition "while result list <= n" or its equivalent would be more bytes than what i use with `echo` and `^:_`.  if i only have to express "do this n times" that would be a different story.  it looks like "do this n*n times" would probably be safe, though, but then you'd have to pluck the first n at the end....

Answer (score 3):

## Vyxal, <sup>8</sup> 5 bytes

**Huge thanks to @Lyxal for -3 bytes using a filter lambda, so I could beat all!**

```
'ǐG5>
```

Takes an integer input \$n\$, and outputs all non-hamming numbers \$\le{n}\$ (According to new rule)

**Explanation**

```
'         # Filter lambda
 ǐ        # Prime factors of each number
  G       # Maximum
   5>     # Greater than 5?
          # Implicitly output
```

[Try it!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?flags=&code=%27%C7%90G5%3E&inputs=15&header=&footer=)

Comment: This is the definition of amazing

Comment: This isn't a valid answer any more, you can't take print the numbers below n

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

Uses xnor's idea.

```
foV>5pN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/Py0/zM60wO//fwA)

Outputs an infinite list.

```
foV>5pN
      N  From the infinite list of natural numbers,
f        keep the ones that satisfy the following predicate
  V      There exists
     p   a prime factors
   >5    that is greater than 5
```

Comment: Crap, beat me to it, was literally about to post fȯ>5▼pN

Comment: @rak1507 You can still post it, it's a bit different.

Comment: just realised it's wrong anyway :P oh well

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `lists.lazy math.primes.factors math.unicode`, 51 bytes

```
1 lfrom [ factors [ 5 > ] ∃ ] lfilter [ . ] leach
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQk1lcUgwh9XISqyoVchNLMsCEXkFRZm5qsV4aWH0xRKw0LzM5PyVVoaAotaSkEqgir0ShOLWwNDUvObVYwZrrv6FCTlpRfq5CtAJMX7SCqYKdQqzCo45mIJmTlplTkloEFNUD8VITkzP@/wcA)

### Explanation:

It's a full program that prints non-Hamming numbers forever, using @xnor's tip about prime factors greater than 5.

- `1 lfrom` An infinite lazy list of the natural numbers.
- `[ factors [ 5 > ] ∃ ] lfilter` Select numbers with a prime factor greater than 5. `∃` is shorthand for `any?` and this turns out to be 1 byte shorter than `supremum 5 >`.
- `[ . ] leach` Print every item in the list.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 25 bytes

```hs
[n|n<-[1..],mod(30^n)n>0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfYRvzPzqvJs9GN9pQTy9WJzc/RcPMIC5PM8/OIPZ/bmJmnm1BUWZeiV5JYnaqgpGBSsb/f8lpOYnpxf91kwsKAA)

The infinite list of non-Hamming numbers.

### How?

A positive integer \$n\$ is Hamming if and only if \$n\$ divides \$30^n\$.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>69</s> <s>70</s> <s>69</s> 67 bytes

```r
while(T<-T+1)for(i in 1:T+6)if(sum(!i%%2:i)<2&!T%%i){show(T);break}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzwjMydVI8RGN0TbUDMtv0gjUyEzT8HQKkTbTDMzTaO4NFdDMVNV1cgqU9PGSE0xRFU1U7O6OCO/XCNE0zqpKDUxu/b/fwA)

xnor's idea in base R.

*+1 thanks to [@Dominic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen) spotting an error and then -1 golfing `print` to `show`.*

Comment: Er, I think you're correct to be suspicious of the ```next```: [try it without next](https://tio.run/##rY/dCoJAEEbv9ylGZLcdKlAvCkzrJfYFJFYc8AfWFZPo2a2ttH2AruYMH/Nxxswj2arVN5tfJc5jRbWWUmV7tY1RiBfFUYRYdkYSUAvHVCGVsh8aGRDnSUqYJSJQnJNQ5wPevboFdwpPbj7mEKyZgCy4qBss2ErDxmUbZhqpkH2DRYj9R@jX6G2rFguhMNq5TG@hvmj0hRV1vX6Q597dR9KRb8vmJw)...

Comment: (but I think that the problem is that ```next``` isn't doing what you want: you're getting ```77``` twice, for instance...)

Comment: A horrible [fix for +8 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcFLCoAgEADQs7hQZqgWuSgQ6RRzAYmkATPxQ3h6ey@P8d0cLiC70LQie3CxQ3EphQ67odm3eFZ@IzCW9oBgKbVhtFoJkpIVHRsipsyxAuEYPw)

Comment: @DominicvanEssen thanks for spotting the `77` error - I think `break` should do the trick for +1: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzwjMydVI8RGN0TbUDMtv0gjUyEzT8HcKkQzM02juDRXQzFTVdXIKlPTxkhNMURVNVMtxM5Ms7qgKDOvRCNE0zqpKDUxu/b/fwA "R – Try It Online"). 
But I still don't like it :(

Comment: Looks good now, and you can [have your byte back](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzwjMydVI8RGN0TbUDMtv0gjUyEzT8HcKkQzM02juDRXQzFTVdXIKlPTxkhNMURVNVMtxM5Ms7o4I79cI0TTOqkoNTG79v9/AA)...

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (Browser), 31 bytes

```javascript
for(k=1n;;)30n**++k%k&&alert(k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z@Yk1pUYpucn1ecn5Oql5OfrpeUmZeiARXQ/J@WX6SRbWuYZ22taWyQp6WlrZ2tmq2mBtamka35/z8A)

Comment: +1, You are always beating Arnauld :-)

Comment: @Wasif Maybe due to the fact that Arnauld is more active than me on PPCG. As a result, Arnauld often posts answer before I ever checked the question. And I will _not_ post my answer if it is not quite interesting (longer than existed answers).

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 26 bytes

```ruby
1.step{|x|30**x%x>0&&p(x)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/31CvuCS1oLqmosbYQEurQrXCzkBNrUCjQrP2/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 44 bytes

```
K`
"$+"{`$
_
)+`^((_+)(?=\2{1,4}$))*_$
$&_
_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/3zuBS0lFW6k6QYUrnktTOyFOQyNeW1PD3jbGqNpQx6RWRVNTK16FS0Utniv@/39TAA) Outputs the `n`th number. No test suite because of the way the program uses history. Explanation:

```
K`
```

Delete the input, replacing it with unary 0.

```
"$+"{`
)`
```

Repeat the input number of times.

```
$
_
```

Increment the current value.

```
+`^((_+)(?=\2{1,4}$))*_$
```

While the current value is a product of powers of 2, 3, 4 or 5...

```
$&_
```

... increment it.

```
_
```

Convert the result to decimal.

To convert the script into one that outputs the first `n` numbers:

- Remove the `)` at the beginning of the 4th line
- Prefix `` .*\` `` to the last line.

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>137</s> 89 bytes

```powershell
filter d{param($b)if($_%$b){$_}else{$_/$b|d $b}}1.."$args"|d 3|d 5|d 2|?{++$t;$_-1}|%{$t}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYjLCoMwEAB/RWQFRXzjqYd@Skh0bYWIsgn0kOy3b/cwzDDP/UMKX/S@225CkeP0EanY02PJXjW45jxqMJVGAsPoA6oHcHkvwDFPfV@CpU8odSzKqsz5ndoW4gtMN3GuEkQWkXUc/w)

Thanks [mazzy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80745/mazzy)!

Comment: nice. you can save some bytes with `filter` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxBCsIwEAC/UssKG0OwauvFx5TWbjAQTdmmiKR5e1zEw1yGYebwJl4e5L25B6ZS5oGHJ8KqrPORuJrS34zKWWyvxr2wBoT@KKbe9lU8fJRK0GfyC6Wf36YKxpxtYLyB09r4CKsJvJNtkgtqDVGii9AJZ2VOsog5l1K6pvkC "PowerShell Core – Try It Online")

Comment: ...and some bytes more [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxBCsIwEEWvUmGEhBBala48TGnaCQZGUqYpLuKcPY7i4m0e/78tv5D3BxL5JTO2ts08Pw0cNiYqyN1a/ybYFA1MPYTzxVaYBGnH@hPvtYMgEjObOyTnPBU4fOaTZqq@jHNQdHRTRuVq/TdRRFpr4zB8AA "PowerShell Core – Try It Online")

Comment: I don't understand why you check the `$u` for zero [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LchBCoMwEEbhq7j4BYNoTYurLnqUYOpIhRQlRrqYzNmnoXTxwePt24fi8aIQuucWSXWf4vRucJplDYliNfP/eLMuDdwFvraG4YTCQfwbea7gRWzf4yx9K8bimh/ctkh3uM5KrhlJVHUchi8 "PowerShell Core – Try It Online")

Comment: ...and final [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYjLCoMwEAB/RWQFRXzjqYd@Skh0bYWIsgn0kOy3b/cwzDDP/UMKX/S@225CkeP0EanY02PJXjW45jxqMJVGAsPoA6oHcHkvwDFPfV@CpU8odSzKqsz5ndoW4gtMN3GuEkQWkXUc/w "PowerShell Core – Try It Online")

Comment: ok, my bad, I didn't see the `or` between all the rules and tried to make work the `no parameter` and the give `n` numbers out, and probably some good golfing you did !
I didn't know you could pass parameters to filters!

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>14</s> 12 bytes

```
7W=hTI<5ePTT
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/3zzcNiPE08Y0NSAk5P9/AA)

Prints the infinite sequence.

```
7     # First print 7 separately.
W     # While
T     # Initialized to 10 by default
=hT   # Increment T by 1
PT    # Lists prime factors of T in increasing order.
>ePT5 # If the highest prime factor is greater than 5, then
T     # Print T
```

*-2 bytes thanks to kops*

Comment: [12 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/3zzcNiPE08Y0NSAk5P9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Outputs the first `n` terms.

```
Èk d¨7}jU
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=yGsgZKg3fWpV&input=NQ)

```
Èk d¨7}jU     :Implicit input of integer U
È             :Function taking an integer as input
 k            :  Prime factors
   d          :  Any?
    ¨7        :    Greater than equal to 7
      }       :End function
       jU     :Get the first U integers that return true
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/) + gmp, <s>37</s> 51 bytes

*Edit: +14 bytes after the rules were changed to disallow outputting all non-Hamming numbers up to `n`: now outputs the infinite list*

```r
n=gmp::as.bigz(1);repeat if(60^(n=n+1)%%n>0)show(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfk5lUlFhUqZGeW6D5P88WSFlZJRbrJWWmV2kYaloXpRakJpYoZKZpmBnEaeTZ5mkbaqqq5tkZaBZn5Jdr5Gn@/w8A)

Outputs infinite list of non-Hamming numbers.

Uses arbitrary-precision calculations to simply check whether `n` divides the `n`th power of 60 (this is sufficient to be certain that it also can't divide any higher power of 60).  We could have stopped at the `floor(log2(n))`th power of 60, but it would have made an annoyingly long program.

Of course, the mathematics itself is correct even without the `gmp` library to handle the actual abritrary-precision calculations... so we could have an even shorter version in base-[R](https://www.r-project.org/) if we don't mind going out-of-range for "huge" non-Hamming numbers:

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>35</s> 44 bytes

*Edit: +9 bytes to comply with the changed rules*

```r
repeat if(30^(log2(T<-T+1)%/%1)%%T>0)show(T)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vyi1IDWxRCEzTcPYIE4jJz/dSCPERjdE21BTVV8VSKiG2BloFmfkl2uEaP7/DwA)

Same approach as above, but goes out-of-range for "huge" non-Hamming numbers, defined as any number greater than 16383.

If we are somewhat more timid and define a "huge" to be any number greater than 12 (and accept that above this the program will output junk or crash), then we can have an even shorter <s>23-byte</s> 34-byte solution of just `repeat if(30^(T<-T+1)%%T>0)show(T)` [Try it!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vyi1IDWxRCEzTcPYIE4jxEY3RNtQU1U1xM5Aszgjv1wjRPP/fwA).

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
üu§└ÿà♦
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=817515c0988504&i=15)

<del>TIL that `|M` returns infinity for empty lists</del>. Found a method without `|M`.

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 56 bytes

inspired by [Julian's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223827/80745) (loop instead recursion)

```powershell
1.."$args"|?{$a=$_;2,3,5|%{for(;!($a%$_)){$a/=$_}};$a-1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/f/fUE9PSSWxKL1Yqca@WiXRViXe2kjHWMe0RrU6Lb9Iw1pRQyVRVSVeUxMoqQ@Ura21VknUNaz9//@/qYEBAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 23 bytes

```
≔⁰θＦＮ«≦⊕θＷ¬﹪Ｘ³⁰θθ≦⊕θ⟦Ｉθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@xuDgzPU/DQEehUNOaKy2/SEHDM6@gtMSvNDcptUhDU1OhmovTN7EAqs4zL7koNTc1ryQ1BaKDszwjMydVQcMvv0TDNz@lNCdfIyC/HKjTGGwkCAPNwGdAQFFmXolGtHNicYlGoWYsUKj2/3/T/7plOQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs the first `n` numbers. Explanation: Uses @Delfad0r's approach.

```
≔⁰θ
```

Start at zero.

```
ＦＮ«
```

Repeat `n` times.

```
≦⊕θ
```

Increment the accumulator.

```
Ｗ¬﹪Ｘ³⁰θθ
```

While it divides its power of `30`...

```
≦⊕θ
```

... increment it.

```
⟦Ｉθ
```

Output the found value on its own line.

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), <sup><s>[44](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/213718)</s></sup> 43 bytes

```sh
seq inf|factor|grep ' 7
 .[^ ]'|cut -d: -f1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@K/xvzi1UCEzL60mLTG5JL@oJr0otUBBXcGcS0EvOk4hVr0mubREQTfFSkE3zfC/Zk1GamKKgq6hgcF/AA)

-1 thanks to @tail spark rabbit ear

- `seq inf`: count up infinitely
- `factor`ise each number in the form `52: 2 2 13`
- `grep`: keep only lines matching the `r`egular `e`xpression  `7\n .[^ ]`

  - The newline acts like "or"
  - Essentially matches either a factor that starts with 7, or a factor with more than one digit. This will match any prime > 5, so as long as there's at least one matching factor, the whole line will be printed
- `cut -d: -f1`: take the first field (where fields are separated by colons) of each line. This gets only the number itself

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 45 bytes

```sh
for ((;++a;)){>`factor $a`;><7->&&<<<$a;rm *}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpBCsIwEAXQq3ywhMTiwpWLhJylg0zpQNOEzhRR8eyx28f76NJ9n@sO7@M4Ugzhm6eZnnbSQFPM6XHLzqWUBop7wfXXg9OVueGOCwgqpa0Mk8L1MIjCFgaTCqvhRW9YhVptkG2WTYxxvnZY/wM)

- `for ((;++a;)){}`: for each integer up to infinity:

  - `factor $a`: factorise the number in the form `52: 2 2 13`
  - ``` >`` ```: create the files according to the words in the factorisation (e.g. `52:`, `2` (duplicates are just ignored), and `13`)
  - `<7->`: look for a file which is a number greater than or equal to 7

    - If the number has a prime factor greater than 5, it is not a Hamming number and will be matched
    - The number itself always has a trailing colon, so it can never be matched by this
  - `>`: and try to output to it
  - `&&`: if that works, then:

    - `<<<$a`: print the number
  - `rm *`: remove all the files (so we're fresh for the next iteration)

Comment: [43 bytes](https://tio.run/##qyrO@K/xvzi1UCEzL60mLTG5JL@oJr0otUBBXcGcS0EvOk4hVr0mubREQTfFSkE3zfC/Zk1GamKKgq6hgcF/AA "Zsh – Try It Online"): no ERE needed in this case because separating BREs with LFs stands for `|` in ERE when `grep`ing.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 66 bytes

It was easier to generate many (seven) times as many numbers as needed, then trim the excess:

```
h(n)=select(x->factor(x)[,1][-1..-1][1]>5,vector(7*n,i,i+1))[1..n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HclBCoAgEADA7@yWK3mQTvkR8SBhuRAmJuHvTTrNYbIvTGfuPULC7QlX2Cs0Moff612goRXKWVJS0lA5o8Ub/lqnJFjwrBDt6OR6LpwqRNALYv8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 56 bytes

Generates an infinite sequence of non-Hamming numbers

```
i=7;while(1,if(factor(i)[,1][-1..-1][1]>5,print(i));i++)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/j/P9PW3Lo8IzMnVcNQJzNNIy0xuSS/SCNTM1rHMDZa11BPTxdIG8bameoUFGXmlQBlNK0ztbU1//8HAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 235 bytes

```powershell
param($k)$s='$f;$n/=$f';function F($n){$m=[math]::sqrt($n);$f=2;while(!($n%$f)){iex $s};$f=3;while($f-le$m-and$n-ge$m){while(!($n%$f)){iex $s};$f+=2};$n};$a=@();$a=@();$g=1;while($a.length-lt$k){$j=(F($g)[-1])-gt5;if($j){$a+=$g}$g++}$a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY5BCsIwFESvojDShBKliiCGD668hHQRNEmradQ2olB69piCunMxzDCP/5nb9anbrtLOxXhTrWoYLhwdZTASfkEwmTQPfwz11U/2DJ73aOjQqFCV2213b8PYSRhaymdVO82mqZjBcN7X@jVBN4xw9YEwwmk0QvkTvLAp8v7/WU7LZD5J0Y7xn1kqvv/U3GlvQyVcSMN7nImllZYfRFFyYcNa1obhnIjKCXaAzfMBKsa4eQM)

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 0.4](http://julialang.org/), 52 bytes

```
x=1;while x>0 keys(factor(x+=1))⊆1:5||print(-x)end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUz8/7/C1tC6PCMzJ1Whws5AITu1slgjLTG5JL9Io0Lb1lBT81FXm6GVaU1NQVFmXomGboVmal7K//8A)

I'm using Julia 0.4 for `factor`, which was then moved in the package `Primes.jl`

also works with recent versions of Julia + Primes.jl

`factor(x)` returns a `Dict` with the keys been the prime factors and the values the exponent of each factor

in more recent version with `Primes.jl`, `factor(Set,x)` can be called instead for the same result

Answer (score 0):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 92 bytes

Previously 93 bytes that outputs intfinite list.

Given a line of an integer \$n\$, outputs first \$n\$ nunbers.

Pretty naïve.

```
{for(k=j=7;$0--;k=++j){for(;k%2-1;k/=2);for(;!(k%3);k/=3);for(;!(k%5);k/=5);if(k>1)print j}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/Oi2/SCPbNsvW3FrFQFfXOttWWztLEyxqna1qpGtona1va6RpDRZQ1MhWNdYEiRgjiZiCRYBkZppGtp2hZkFRZl6JQlZt7f//hgYGAA)

Comment: FYI inversing the conditions on this program does not pass the original task because of time limitation.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>38</s> <s>37</s> 35 bytes

```python
x=1
while[30**x%x>0==print(x)]:x+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8LWkKs8IzMnNdrYQEurQrXCzsDWtqAoM69Eo0Iz1qpC29bw/38A)

Where'd the python answers go???

Port of [G.B.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223845/109916)'s answer.

-2 thx to @Steffan

Comment: [35 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8LWkKs8IzMnNdrYQEurQrXCzsDWtqAoM69Eo0Iz1qpC29bw/38A "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 16 bytes

```
7`Đϼ6<Π?ŕ:ŕĐƥ;⁺ł
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9weXT//zdgxJDPvDY8zqA/xZU6xZXEkMalO@KBusWC//8)

Prints the list of Hamming numbers without end.

```
7                     push 7 (the first Hamming number)
 `             ł      do... while the top of stack is truthy
  Đ                   Đuplicate
   ϼ                  get unique ϼrime factors
    6<Π?              are they all less than 6?
        ŕ             if so, ŕemove top of stack
         :ŕĐƥ         otherwise; ŕemove top of stack, Đuplicate top of stack,
                      and ƥrint top of stack
             ;⁺       either way, increment top of stack
```